# MongoDB MongoCollection: Cannot update field

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to update a single document in my mongodb collection as

```
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();

/*Some processing to add stuff to jsonArr*/

mongoCollection.updateOne(eq("key", _id),Updates.set("asd", jsonArr));
```

but i get

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class org.json.simple.JSONObject.
at org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecCache.getOrThrow(CodecCache.java:46)
at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:63)
at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ChildCodecRegistry.get(ChildCodecRegistry.java:51)
at org.bson.codecs.IterableCodec.writeValue(IterableCodec.java:105)
at org.bson.codecs.IterableCodec.encode(IterableCodec.java:90)
at org.bson.codecs.IterableCodec.encode(IterableCodec.java:37)
at com.mongodb.client.model.BuildersHelper.encodeValue(BuildersHelper.java:35)
at com.mongodb.client.model.Updates$SimpleUpdate.toBsonDocument(Updates.java:442)
at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.toBsonDocument(MongoCollectionImpl.java:599)
at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.update(MongoCollectionImpl.java:542)
at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.updateOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:381)
at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.updateOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:376)
```

note that, here is how i had originally created the document in the first place

```
        Document unprocessedMeta = new Document("key",_id);

        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
        /*some processing to add stuff to arr */

        unprocessedMeta.append("asd", arr);
        mongoCollection.insertOne(unprocessedMeta);
```

and this worked just fine. 
Note that the `asd` key has a `JSONArray` as its value. Also, i can select the document by

`Document d = mongoCollection.find(eq("key", _id)).first();`

and it shows up just as expected

```
Document{{_id=5981e702324fb0b50d727fe7, key=2323, asd=[Document{{<some-key-value-pairs>}}]}}
```

and i can get the inner `JSONArray` as

```
JSONArray existingAsd = (JSONArray) d.get("asd");
```

and i can iterate over the `existingAsd` and access the objects.

Why cant i update? Basically, i want to replace the value of the key `asd` in the document that matches `key`. I have even tried

```
mongoCollection.updateOne(eq("key", _id),Updates.unset("asd"));
        mongoCollection.updateOne(eq("key", _id),Updates.set("asd", jsonArr));
```

but i get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MongoDB operates using BSON, I believe it's because there is no JSONObject to BSON serializer.

Try using a `List<Document>` instead:

```
// id of the document
Document id = new Document("key", 1);

// array of documents
List<Document> docArray = Arrays.asList(
    new Document("key1", "val1"),
    new Document("key2", "val2"));

// insert the new document
Document doc = new Document("key", 1).append("docarray", docArray);
collection.insertOne(doc);
System.out.println("Before: " + collection.find(id).first().toJson());

// new array of documents
List<Document> docArrayUpdated = Arrays.asList(
    new Document("key3", "val3"),
    new Document("key4", "val4"));

// update the document with the new array
collection.updateOne(id, Updates.set("docarray", docArrayUpdated));
System.out.println("After: " + collection.find(id).first().toJson());
```

The code above printed:

```
Before: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5982cf6f11e67733e5efcea6" }, "key" : 1, "docarray" : [{ "key1" : "val1" }, { "key2" : "val2" }] }
After: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5982cf6f11e67733e5efcea6" }, "key" : 1, "docarray" : [{ "key3" : "val3" }, { "key4" : "val4" }] }
```

which showed that the `docarray` field was updated successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mongoCollection.updateOne(eq("key", _id),new Document("$set", new Document("asd", jsonArr)));`

Comment: thanks, but now i get

`Cannot update {"ert":"dvwmv","zxc":"inin","qaz":"mnmnbm","tt":24889} 
com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$numberLong' in 'imageList.0.tt.$numberLong' is not valid for storage.`

Comment: does it have something to do with the numeric filed/value?

Comment: Do you have a `$push` (or other expression) inside the `$set`? Can you show the data structure you would like to write into MongoDB?